# Как разместить изображение в указанное место в сетке grid (bootstrapv4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="img/icon/customize.png">
                <p class="h3block2">Accusan timar</p><br/>
                <p class="h4block2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantiu</p>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Boostrap есть медиа объекты (почитать можно [здесь](http://bootstrap-v4.ru/layout/media-object/))

```css
.marginr-46{
  margin-right: 46px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="media">
   <img class="marginr-46"   src="http://www.generalcable.su/images/ico-flex.png" alt="media">
   <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Accusan timar</h5>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque   laudantiu
   </div>
</div>
```